# MSSQL: left join on MAX()

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, max, sqlsrv

Is there a better (more performant) way to join on the MAX(id) (without using a subselect) than my actual way? We are dealing with huge databases and are trying to optimize as much as possible

```
SELECT e.*, r.report_name FROM report r 
LEFT JOIN engineer e ON e.id = r.id
WHERE e.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM engineer WHERE process = r.process)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `process = process` is always true and your left join is in reality a inner join BTW

Comment: r.process typo corrected

Comment: can you add a few rows of sample data and the desired output please?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you

```
WHERE e.id = (SELECT top 1 id 
              FROM engineer 
              WHERE process =r.process
              order by id desc)
```

Comment: please explain why this answer is not useful?

Comment: thanks, that seems to be faster then using max! So no way to eliminate the subselect? (I didn't downvote you, btw)

Comment: i edited the query so you can do it without sub select

Comment: You cannot use functions like MAX OR AVG in a where clause or on join :( thats why I used the subselect in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I think thats better

```
SELECT TOP 1 e.*, r.report_name FROM report r 
LEFT JOIN engineer e ON e.id = r.id
ORDER BY e.id desc
```

Comment: Report can have more than 1 result. But each of these should be joined on the corresponding process in engineer with the max id.

Comment: I got it. I encountered a similar situation and had worked faster then subquery.First get max id some variable and use main query.

Answer (score 0):

One other option: pre-aggregate the entire set, then `JOIN` to it to filter your other tables. This will treat it like a table, rather than executing the same SELECT for every single row that you run into; set-based logic versus row-by-agonizing-row.

```
SELECT 
    e.*, 
    r.report_name 
FROM 
    report r 
     INNER JOIN -- the WHERE clause effectively makes this an INNER JOIN, so changed for readability
    engineer e ON 
        e.id = r.id
     INNER JOIN 
      (
        SELECT Process, MAX(ID) MaxID
        FROM Engineer 
        GROUP BY Process 
      ) eMax ON 
        e.Process = eMax.Process AND
        e.ID = eMax.MaxID
```